# How to get Radius of Blue Range Circle at My Location in Google Map - iOS SDK

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I need to get radius of light blue range circle, so that I can send the accuracy of my location to other device. But not sure how to get range circle radius from Google Map iOS SDK.

Comment: As google map showing accuracy of my location range in a light blue circle with blue dot. I don't know these range is exposed.

Comment: May I know why this question got down vote. If a member downvoted, he should include the reason. So that the person asked question will know the reason and wont do it again. Down voting and not adding reason is really annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `myLocation` property of the `GMSMapView` is a [`CLLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CLLocation), which has a `horizontalAccuracy` property. This is probably what the Google Maps SDK is using to draw the circle.

Comment: Thanks a lot. With that horizantalAccuracy I can send how accurate my location to the receiver and draw circle as my location is doing. Great!